# KnockoutJS observable not updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Hi I am new to knockoutjs and started learning from the Tutorial in their site.

Observable arrays are supposed to update all the bindings in a page. I am practicing in JsFiddle and my bindings are not being updated dynamically.

What am I doing wrong?

[JSFiddle Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/crkc/gyW2k/4/)

I am expecting that if we type in the textboxes it should update the table!

JS Code:

```
var viewmodel = {
    posts: ko.observableArray(data)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that calling `posts: ko.observableArray(data)` will make only data observable, and not its elements. To make an entire object tree observable, you can use the mapping plugin, like in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gyW2k/7/

The only change to the code is:

```
var viewmodel = {
    posts: ko.mapping.fromJS(data)
};
```

ko mapping docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But still my blog names are not updating. Is there anything else i have to do. Thanks for the documentation link

Comment: That happens because the object structures are different. Look at the first and second records in the data array and you will notice the differences. The first record works fine, but the second has a different structure and doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks again! Reading the documentation link, very helpful!

Comment: don't fall into the mapping trap and assume it's going to solve all your problems...be sure you understand what it's creating.